# User Access management in mysql/php web page

Tags: mysql, database-design, user-controls, relational-database

I am making a semi-simple web application for my mother using php, mysql, and javascript.

She is a teacher, and this wil allow her to manage various components of her lesson plans. 
For each component there is a table, and for each component that can contain another component there is another table that holds the relationship. (That table type has two columns each has a foreign key to the related tables)

I am nearly done, but she now wants to allow her friends to use this, I don't care too much about sql injection, but I would like to implement User Control so that only users that create a component can view and edit that component.

I also want them to be able to make public components, so that users can copy components to their own dataset.

**My question** To implement the user control should I have each user have there own database instant, or should each table have an owner column and column for public/private status, or is there another alternative that I have not thought of.

An issue that I see is that it would require additional mysql query when creating the relations between components because I would need to check that both components user tag matches the current user.

Any feedback/suggestions are helpful

**Update** The only people using/accessing this will be other teachers, that will be developing their own lesson plans

Comment: By her friends, do you mean they would be teachers with their own lesson plans, or users that would view hers? Makes a big difference in terms of relationships.

Comment: Only other teachers will be viewing this, and they will be using it to develop/organize their lesson plans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would certainly implement this within the same database. Having a different database for each user is not a good solution in this case. Think, for example, how you would build a search function if each user's data is in a separate database will clashing UIDs. It would be a nightmare. Separate databases work where each database serves a separate application and there are precisely zero relations between the data in different databases.

So that brings you on to how to implement it. This will depend on your model. Will each lesson plan only ever have, for example, one and only one owner? If so, then adding that info to the components table might work. Or else you might need a separate table to define ownership and hence access to the different components. Either way, I would make sure the access logic is decoupled and encapsulated in your application to make sure you can change it in the future. Imagine for example you start with a simple, single-owner model but the site grows and grows and soon groups of people all need ownership/edit access to components.